# VBA Function to insert comment based on offset cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets. One is a long term plan calendar, with dates on the top and objects on the left. The other worksheet is the data sheet. Each calendar entry is its own row, and there's one column that has the cell address of the calendar entry for the other sheet. I'm trying to add comments to the calendar worksheet, but am getting an error with the below code. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
Sub UpdateLTP()

    Sheets("Long Term Plan").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.ClearComments
    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("AA2:AA" & Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Long Term Plan").Range(cell.Value).AddComment cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: What error and on what line?

Comment: Should it not be "For Each cell in rng.Cells" to specify where "cell" is looking?

Comment: The error is on the line inserting the actual comment. I've tried changing that line to a MsgBox popup and get no errors, so it must be something with the syntax there.

Comment: The error is Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Cyril, I tried changing that and am getting the same error.

Comment: What is `cell.Value` when it errors?

Comment: cell.Value is (for example) F4, which the cell address of the calendar worksheet.

Comment: What is the **exact** value when it errors? not what it should be, what it is.

Comment: Well, it errors on the first loop, and the first value is F4. I've confirmed this is the cell.Value.

Comment: Add `Sheets("Long Term Plan").Range(cell.Value).ClearComments` before trying to add one.

Comment: Ah, great idea! It appears as though there was one duplicate value in that column. If I change the AddComment to ("test") it now works without errors, but with the offset I am still getting an error.

Comment: Wrap the cell.Offset(0, -1).Value in CStr: `CStr(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)`

Answer (score 0):

This works to create a comment and then add the text to the comment.  The code will error out if the value of the offset cell is nothing.  Adding some error checking would prevent that from happening

```
Sub UpdateLTP()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range

    Sheets("Long Term Plan").Select
    Set xlRange = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    xlRange.ClearComments
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Set xlRange = Range("AA2:AA" & Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Long Term Plan").Range(xlCell.Value)
                .AddComment
                .Comment.Visible = False
                .Comment.Text Text:=xlCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

This code has a check to make sure that the offset cell is not empty

```
Sub UpdateLTP()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range

    Sheets("Long Term Plan").Select
    Set xlRange = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    xlRange.ClearComments
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Set xlRange = Range("AA2:AA" & Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value <> "" Then
            If xlCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
                With Sheets("Long Term Plan").Range(xlCell.Value)
                    .AddComment
                    .Comment.Visible = False
                    .Comment.Text Text:=xlCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the code in a much cleaner way. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error on what seems to be the first loop (as no comments appear on the calendar).

Comment: I've tried making the line .Comment.Text Text:=xlCell.Value (to test) and am getting the same error.

Comment: add the line `Msgbox xlcell.offset(0,-1).value` to the code before it calls the `With Sheets` line and verify that the referenced cell value is not empty

Comment: Also check to make sure that all of the offset callouts are using the **-1** and not **1**

Comment: Okay, I tried this again with just Cell.Value after finding a duplicate in the column and it worked. But I am still getting the error when I try to use the offset. I tried the MsgBox popup and the first offset value was 4, but I still got an error when it tried to run the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. I hope you can get by without an explanation as the code is pretty simple and the difference will help you spot where the errors came to be. I've tested the below code and it works fine. Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateLTP()
Dim xlCell, xlRange, SourceRange As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer
Set SourceRange = Sheets("Data").Range("AA2:AA" & Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each xlCell In SourceRange
        If xlCell.Value <> "" Then
            If xlCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
                With Sheets("Long Term Plan").Cells(xlCell.Row, xlCell.Column)
                    '' Clear Comments as needed from our source sheet.
                    .ClearComments
                    .AddComment (CStr(xlCell.Offset(0, -1).Value))
                    '' Please change to false as needed.
                    .Comment.Visible = True
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next xlCell
End Sub
```